# Pandas .sub() works, but subtract operator fails

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subtract columns of of type `datetime` in a Pandas dataframe, `s`.

```
[in] s.shape
[out] (1381,5)
```

Dates in column `t1`:

```
[in] s['t1'].tail(3)
[out] 56   2013-01-01
      62   2013-01-01
      63   2013-01-01
      Name: t1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Dates in column `t2`:

```
[in] s['t2'].tail(3)
[out] 56   2013-01-02
      62   2013-01-02
      63   2013-01-02
      Name: t2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The `.sub()` operator produces the expected result: `d=s['t2'].sub(s['t1'])`.

```
[in] print d.shape
[out] (1381,)

[in] d.tail(3)
[out] 56   1 days
      62   1 days
      63   1 days
      Name: t2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The subtract operator produces an unexpected result: `d=s['t2']-s['t1']`.

```
[in] print d.shape
[out] (4293,)

[out] 592   570 days
      593   660 days
      594   180 days
      dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this has something to do with the data structures in use. There may be a more foolproof, cleaner way of computing date time differences in pandas. Though I have not yet had a chance to look at the documentation in too much detail. Perhaps try `s['t2'].values - s['t1'].values`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `axis` argument in sub() from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1:

```
   df.sub(axis=1) vs df.sub(axis=0)
```

Does one case produce the right result, and one produce result you're getting?  That's likely my guess.

Comment: `sub(,axis=0)` produces the correct results, but `sub(,axis=1)` throw an error because the operation is subtracting two series: `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`